# Property 'spring.cloud.config.server.git.privateKey' is not a valid private key

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, bitbucket, spring-cloud-config

Sort of stuck on above. although i see there are questions asked on same topic, and have tried them but still no resort.

stack im using -> mac(mojave), Intellij, jdk8, generated key using puttygen on mac itself and looks like this, this is only for my local springboot config server.

i have tried 2 ways:
spring.cloud.config.server.git.private-key=-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAssBl7ZADFHBZrSnDPVhClH9HFzCaEPKEaO3MX7H5uBMTEL59\n
CLRguWdCQJnvv2L6vSLyBb9ds05DHEzE2OqkU5VzYX4CCrU7t1ktZmy3cwyNc0g0\n
ijJMInd47KG57Pi6nzpN/bVsLNiwRO3PZ7wUxgeQT6vh5euhBbTlvrFRbNMZm0Rf\n
....
..
,,,
F5vNwcngKk/tFFwX2XooikGliOCxHU66/KOckbNXqOaLBc+QlNsB\n
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

gives error:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.config.server.git' to org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentProperties failed:

```
Reason: Property 'spring.cloud.config.server.git.privateKey' is not a valid private key
```

2) spring.cloud.config.server.git.private-key=~/.ssh/temp/id_rsa
spring.cloud.config.server.git.ignore-local-ssh-settings=true

and still get the same error as i shared above.

3) there was a SO question where solution talked, that the key might not be created right. 
Now i have using the same key for my normal development & been using it fine for a year & have the pub added to my bitbucket repo and it works fine. its our own repo(not git hub) i normally work fine with the key in ~/.ssh/id_rsa. So i created RSA private key from ~/.ssh/id_rsa file into a temp directory and using the same for the config server APP.

4) in the known hosts file, there are about 7 entries 1 of them is the bitbucket server. and its ssh-rsa.

was wondering if there a step-by-step guide or some sample someone can help me with please ?

Comment: So now that the entire planet has your private key, when are you rotating it?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this will help, user 'introtj' commented here [https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1392](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1392#issuecomment-653768827) and this helped me.

```
JGit requires RSA keys in PEM format. Below is an example ssh-keygen (from openssh) command that will generate a key in the corect format:

ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096
```

Update 22-Apr-2021

So today I decided to switch from yml to properties and of course had the same error as above. I knew the key was good because it was working fine in the YAML format. After 2 hours of trial and error I managed to get it working:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.private-key= \
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n\
your_key_here_your_key_here_you\n\
your_key_here_your_key_here_you\n\
your_key_here_your_key_here_you\n\
your_key_here_your_key_here_you\n\
your_key_here_your_key_here_you\n\
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

I am using spring boot 2.4.5 and spring cloud 2020.0.02

Let me know if it is working for you this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `|`

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.private-key= |
                               ----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
                               MIIEpQIBAAKCAQEA3Tz2mr7SZiAMfQyuvBjM9Oi..
                               RK+Lh9x5eJPo5CAZ3/ANBE0sTK0ZsDGMak2m1g7..
                               wnLe4nOb7/eEJbDPkk05ShhBrJGBKKxb8n104o/..
                               5A13wiLitEO7nco2WfyYkQzaxCw0AwzlkVHiIyC..
                               -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for that.. however i still the same error, cant seem to find a way to attach screenshot, but this is what i have in my props now spring.cloud.config.server.git.ignore-local-ssh-settings=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.strictHostKeyChecking=false

spring.cloud.config.server.git.private-key= |
                                        -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----                                           Also, i have the respective public key in my bitbucket already & works fine when i do my normal git activities, so still clueless whats wrong

Comment: exception i get is:  ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.config.server.git' to org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentProperties failed:

    Reason: Property 'spring.cloud.config.server.git.privateKey' is not a valid private key


Action:

Update your application's configuration