# Spring Cloud Config Server gives IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 2d Error

Tags: java, spring, git, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm trying to connect to the bitbucket repo using ssh in the application.properties file.

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=git@prod-cvs2.test.com:7999/properties.git
spring.cloud.config.server.git.ignoreLocalSshSettings=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.hostKey=prod-cvs2.test.com
spring.cloud.config.server.git.hostKeyAlgorithm=ssh-rsa
spring.cloud.config.server.git.strictHostKeyChecking=false
spring.cloud.config.server.git.passphrase=Secret123

spring.cloud.config.server.git.privateKey=-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n\
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED\n\
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,947ABEEB0FE4132D7074662CE7FF5068\n\
\n\
THE_KEY\n\
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=master
```

The config server starts successfully. However, when I try to read the properties from postman it gives me below error.

```
Caused by: org.apache.sshd.common.SshException: DefaultConnectFuture[git@prod-cvs2.test.com/162.134.121.63:22]: Failed (IllegalArgumentException) to execute: Illegal base64 character 2d
    at org.apache.sshd.common.future.AbstractSshFuture.lambda$verifyResult$1(AbstractSshFuture.java:131) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.common.future.AbstractSshFuture.formatExceptionMessage(AbstractSshFuture.java:185) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.common.future.AbstractSshFuture.verifyResult(AbstractSshFuture.java:130) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.client.future.DefaultConnectFuture.verify(DefaultConnectFuture.java:42) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.client.future.DefaultConnectFuture.verify(DefaultConnectFuture.java:34) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.sshd.SshdSession.connect(SshdSession.java:191) ~[org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache-5.13.1.202206130422-r.jar:5.13.1.202206130422-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.sshd.SshdSession.connect(SshdSession.java:142) ~[org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache-5.13.1.202206130422-r.jar:5.13.1.202206130422-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.sshd.SshdSession.connect(SshdSession.java:99) ~[org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache-5.13.1.202206130422-r.jar:5.13.1.202206130422-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.sshd.SshdSessionFactory.getSession(SshdSessionFactory.java:235) ~[org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache-5.13.1.202206130422-r.jar:5.13.1.202206130422-r]
    ... 136 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 2d
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:743) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:535) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:558) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.sshd.common.config.keys.PublicKeyEntryDataResolver.decodeEntryKeyData(PublicKeyEntryDataResolver.java:53) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.common.config.keys.PublicKeyEntry.parsePublicKeyEntry(PublicKeyEntry.java:408) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.common.config.keys.AuthorizedKeyEntry.parseAuthorizedKeyEntry(AuthorizedKeyEntry.java:318) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.common.config.keys.AuthorizedKeyEntry.parseAuthorizedKeyEntry(AuthorizedKeyEntry.java:273) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.ssh.PropertyBasedSshSessionFactory$2.getHostKey(PropertyBasedSshSessionFactory.java:151) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.ssh.PropertyBasedSshSessionFactory$2.lookup(PropertyBasedSshSessionFactory.java:122) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.transport.sshd.JGitServerKeyVerifier.lookup(JGitServerKeyVerifier.java:72) ~[org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache-5.13.1.202206130422-r.jar:5.13.1.202206130422-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.transport.sshd.JGitClientSession.resolveAvailableSignaturesProposal(JGitClientSession.java:275) ~[org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache-5.13.1.202206130422-r.jar:5.13.1.202206130422-r]
    at org.apache.sshd.common.session.helpers.AbstractSession.resolveAvailableSignaturesProposal(AbstractSession.java:2356) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
```

Can someone please guide me on what am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: @SwethaSharma, I do not think having the key there in the first place is a good idea from a security POV. I would go right now into whatever place you have it setup and discard it and create a new one.

Comment: I do not think it's a git problem. You have a problem in the way you are trying to read the key.

Comment: @eftshift0 Thank you for your reply. I'm trying to follow ``` https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_git_ssh_configuration_using_properties ``` document. Here they have put the private key in the application.properties file.

Comment: when I say "having the key _there_" I mean _in the question that you posted_.

Comment: Do you think \n\ or \ is not placed correctly in the key?

Answer (score 0):

> Do you think \n\ or \ is not placed correctly in the key?

Check if, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63695528/6309), you can use

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.private-key= \
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n\
your_key_here_your_key_here_you\n\
your_key_here_your_key_here_you\n\
your_key_here_your_key_here_you\n\
your_key_here_your_key_here_you\n\
your_key_here_your_key_here_you\n\
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

I do not think you should include the

```
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED\n\
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,947ABEEB0FE4132D7074662CE7FF5068\n\
\n\
THE_KEY\n\
```